# Visualizing extra bytes from LAS 1.4 in Potree?

Tags: lidar, visualisation, las, point-cloud, potree

I was wondering if it is possible to visualize the information that can be stored in the extra bytes of the LAS 1.4 file. This could be really helpful for validating features that have been calculate from the point clouds and stored in the extra bytes. The features are written into the .las files with laspy (https://pythonhosted.org/laspy/tut_part_3.html)

I know that it is possible to work/see them in Cloud Compare and LAStools, but it would be faster to view them in a Potree viewer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not currently possible. The laz-perf library that Potree and plas.io depend upon needs an update to support this capability.

Comment: Thanks Howard for your answer. Would it be a good idea to post this question on https://github.com/hobu/laz-perf/issues or https://github.com/potree/potree? Or is this already an issue (could not find it anywhere).

Comment: No need for a ticket. We know about the issue.